# Converting dates into weekdays then correlating it and summing it

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

The query is simple but not functioning the way I want it,
I am trying to check the date I inspected is the correct day I am checking against.

### Input

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date '1982.03.09', 'DAY'), 
(CASE When lower(TO_CHAR(date '1982.03.09', 'DAY')) like lower('TUESDAY') 
      then 1 else 0 end)
```

### Output

[image]

The answer should have been 1 for the case statement.
I added lower to check if it had to something with the capitals

### Reason

The reason why I use a case statement is because when a student has an afterschool activity on monday, I want to place either 1 or 0 in the table and calculate the sum of how many students have afterschool acitivity on monday and so on.

### Need eventually

[image]

I am doing this so that I can create a table of the week with the number of children doing aftershool activities for each day.

Any help regarding fixing my query would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason there are spaces behind the `TUESDAY` `to_char()` produces. You can `trim()` them away. But instead of relying on a string representation (that probably might change when the locale changes) you should better use `extract()` to get the day of the week in numerical representation, `0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday and so on.

```
SELECT to_char(DATE '1982.03.09', 'DAY'),
       CASE
         WHEN trim(to_char(DATE '1982.03.09', 'DAY')) = 'TUESDAY' THEN
           1
         ELSE
           0
       END,
       CASE extract(dow FROM DATE '1982.03.09')
         WHEN 2 THEN
           1
         ELSE
           0
       END;
```

Comment: The reason is: The to_char format mask is fixed width. So has the same length for all week days. So "TUESDAY  " is as long as "WEDNESDAY"

Answer (score 1):

I'm a personal fan of `extract (<datepart> from <date>)` in lieu of `to_char` for problems like this.

Based on the output you are trying to achieve, I might also recommend a poor man's pivot table:

```
select
  student_id,
  max (case when extract (dow from activity_date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as mo,
  max (case when extract (dow from activity_date) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as tu,
  max (case when extract (dow from activity_date) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as we,
  max (case when extract (dow from activity_date) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as th,
  max (case when extract (dow from activity_date) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as fr
from activities
where activity_date between :FROM_DATE and :THRU_DATE
group by
  student_id
```

Normally this would be a good use case for `filter (where`, but that would leave null values on date/student records where there is no activity.  Depending on how you render your output, that may or may not be okay (Excel would handle it fine).

```
select
  student_id,
  max (1) filter (where extract (dow from activity_date) = 1) as mo,
  max (1) filter (where extract (dow from activity_date) = 2) as tu,
  max (1) filter (where extract (dow from activity_date) = 3) as we,
  max (1) filter (where extract (dow from activity_date) = 4) as th,
  max (1) filter (where extract (dow from activity_date) = 5) as fr
from activities
group by
  student_id
```